# TypeError at/xx 'method' object is not subscriptable Django

Tags: python, django

when i try to update i get TypeError,I'm having trouble updating even though I have successfully added and deleted. I'm getting an error even though it just worked, where could I have made a stupid mistake

models.py;

```
class problemduyuru(models.Model):
    olusturulmatarihi = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    duyurutipi = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True)
    incidentno = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True)
    baslangiczamani = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True)
    aciklama = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

views.py;

```
def problemduyurusuupdate(request, id):
    problemmember = problemduyuru.objects.get(id=id)
    problemmember.duyurutipi = request.POST.get['duyurutipi']
    problemmember.incidentno = request.POST['incidentno']
    problemmember.baslangiczamani = request.POST['baslangiczamani']
    problemmember.aciklama = request.POST['aciklama']
    problemmember.olusturulmatarihi = request.POST['olusturulmatarihi']
    problemmember.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Alarmlar was updated successfully!')
    return redirect('/problemduyurusu')
```

HTML;

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" action="problemduyurusuupdate/{{ problemmembers.id }}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="bd-callout bd-callout-danger">
      <div class="bd-calloutic bd-callout-dangeric ">
      <div class="dangericon"></div>
    <h4 id="asynchronous-methods-and-transitions" style="color: #e70800;"><b>Technology Announcements</b></h4>
    <h7 id="asynchronous-methods-and-transitions" style="color:red; font-weight: 400; ">Problem Duyurusu</h7></div>
    
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-duyuru" id="inputGroup-sizing-default" style="font-weight: 500;">Duyuru Tipi:</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ problemmembers.duyurutipi }}" name="duyurutipi" id="duyurutipi" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
</div>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-duyuru" id="inputGroup-sizing-default" style="font-weight: 500;">Incident No:</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ problemmembers.incidentno }}" name="incidentno" id="incidentno" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
</div>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-duyuru" id="inputGroup-sizing-default" style="font-weight: 500;">Başlangıç Zamanı:</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ problemmembers.baslangiczamani }}" name="baslangiczamani" id="baslangiczamani" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
</div>
<div class="input-group mb-3" >
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-duyuru" id="inputGroup-sizing-default" style="font-weight: 500;" disabled>Oluşturma Tarihi:</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ problemmembers.olusturulmatarihi }}" name="olusturulmatarihi" id="olusturulmatarihi" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
</div>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-duyuru" id="inputGroup-sizing-default" style="font-weight: 500;">Açıklama:</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ problemmembers.aciklama }}" name="aciklama" id="aciklama" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
</div>
    <br>
  </div>
```

Comment: You should pay attention to the error message and which line it tells you caused the error, pasting the traceback here would also help people debug the issue. The error is with this line `problemmember.duyurutipi = request.POST.get['duyurutipi']`, you need to remove `.get` or replace the key lookup (square brackets) with a method call to `get`

Comment: hi im getting same error;     problemmember.duyurutipi = request.POST['duyurutipi'] @IainShelvington

Answer (score 0):

Your views.py should be :

```
def problemduyurusuupdate(request, id):
    problemmember = problemduyuru.objects.get(id=id)
    problemmember.duyurutipi = request.POST.get('duyurutipi')
    problemmember.incidentno = request.POST.get('incidentno')
    problemmember.baslangiczamani = request.POST.get('baslangiczamani')
    problemmember.aciklama = request.POST.get('aciklama')
    problemmember.olusturulmatarihi = request.POST.get('olusturulmatarihi')
    problemmember.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Alarmlar was updated successfully!')
    return redirect('/problemduyurusu')
```